# MonthToDate errors in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to produce a report that will provide what was shipped out from the 1st of the current month to the current day.  I found something called MonthToDate.  Thought, that was pretty simple until I tried using it.

Seems like no matter what I change, I get `"A String is required here"` error message.

```
{@shipdate}=If {C_SHIP_HIST.SHIPDATE} in MonthToDate Then
{C_SHIP_HIST.ARINVT_ID} Else
"TG"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank-you for your help

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong.. you can't take one argument as `number` and one argument as `String` in `if`. Try below

```
If {C_SHIP_HIST.SHIPDATE} in MonthToDate Then
{@shipdate}=ToText({C_SHIP_HIST.ARINVT_ID})
 Else {@shipdate}="TG"
```